# Image in Java web service

Tags: java, image, web-services, amazon-web-services, imagesource

I am developing the server part in a java Restful web service (using apache tomcat), I am planning to deploy it on cloud web service. 
I want my web service to provide images to client (mobile devices or browsers), user can upload or replace the images dynamically later.

Question 1:
Where should I store the images at server ?
Options--
1].Save the images in database (as blob)
2].Local file system of server.

Question 2:
How to process the client request
Options--
1].I can retrieve it locally and give the image as response.
2].I can give the Public URL of the image as response, and the client can download it from this url.

Can anyone suggest me what option I should opt to optimize the server side processing and storage cost, also w.r.t security.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: while it is the subject to some debate, the usual answer is: local file system. You can add an entry in the database with the location of the file and some metadata but the actual binary blob should be on the file system.

Answer 2: If you simply pass along a public URL, this supposes that you have a public http server that can access and provide the images requested. If this is the case I would consider opting for this because HTTP servers can optimize out of the box (e.g. caching) plus it can offer reuse (e.g. embed the image elsewhere using the public URL).

Comment: Thanks. I have very little knowledge of public http server. As images can be personal photos, I feel that using URL can cause security problem,  am I right ?

Comment: You could still use the URL-methodology if they are personal photo's but then I would advise securing the HTTP endpoint. This of course minimizes the reusability argument of my second answer. You could however let the user decide if they want it private or public (default private).